# R - help me to scrape links from webpage

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm scraping the data from IMDB movie list.
I would like to scrape link for each movie, but not able to correctly identify where it is stored on the page.

This is how the part of the link is stored:
[link screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bISth.jpg)

What I have tried:

```r
link<-html_nodes(strona_int, '.lister-item-header+ a href')
link<-html_text(link)
```

Whole code

```
install.packages("rvest")
install.packages("RSelenium")
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)

#open webprowser (in my case Firefox, but can be chrome or internet explorer)
rD <- rsDriver(browser=c("firefox"))
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

#set the start number for page link
ile<-seq(from=1, by=250, length.out = 1)

#empty frame for data
filmy_df=data.frame()

#loop reading the data
for (j in ile){
  #set the link for webpage
  newURL<-"https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&release_date=,2018-12-31&count=250&start="
  startNumberURL<-paste0(newURL,j)

#open webpage
remDr$navigate(startNumberURL)

#read html code of the page
strona_int<-read_html(startNumberURL)

#rank section
rank_data<-html_nodes(strona_int,'.text-primary')
#konwersja rankingu na text
rank_data<-html_text(rank_data)
#konwersja na numeric
rank_data<-as.numeric(rank_data)

link<-html_nodes(strona_int, '.lister-item-header+ a href')
link<-html_text(link)

#release date
year<-html_nodes(strona_int,'.lister-item-year')
#konwersja na text
year<-html_text(year)
#usuniecie non numeric
year<-gsub("\\D","",year)
#ustawienie jako factor
year<-as.factor(year)

#title
title_data<-html_nodes(strona_int,'.lister-item-header a')
#konwersja tytulu na text
title_data<-html_text(title_data)

#temporary data frame
filmy_df_temp<-data.frame(Rank=rank_data,Title=title_data,Release.Year=year)

#temp df to target df
filmy_df<-rbind(filmy_df,filmy_df_temp)
}

#close browser
remDr$close()
#stop Selenium
rD[["server"]]$stop()
```

**Expected solution:**
Scraped link for the each film which could be used later if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium is not required for gathering the links.

The links are `a` tags housed within a parent with class `lister-item-header`. You can match on those then extract the `href` attribute. You need to add the protocol and domain of "https://www.imdb.com"

In the css selector:

```
.lister-item-header a
```

The dot is a [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) for the parent class; the space between is a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator); the final `a` is a [type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors) for the child `a` tags.

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

url <- "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&release_date=,2018-12-31&count=250&start="
links <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes(., ".lister-item-header a") %>% html_attr(., "href")
```

One way of adding protocol and domain:

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(xml2)

base <- 'https://www.imdb.com'
url <- "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&release_date=,2018-12-31&count=250&start="
links <- url_absolute(read_html(url) %>% html_nodes(., ".lister-item-header a") %>% html_attr(., "href"), base)
```

Reference:

1. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xml2/versions/1.2.0/topics/url_absolute
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: Selenium is required to open next pages. rvest will scrap the content, but I'm scraping multiple pages.

Comment: ok :-)... but your question is how to get all the links - that is what the above does.

Comment: Great! Works. Thank you for reminding me that I can use additional levels to scrap data.
Additional question: to what I can convert it, or it can be stored as attribute? As you can see in the code I'm converting the rest to text or numeric, but for arrtibute there is error.

Comment: Run my code as is and you get a character vector of all links

Comment: I'm new here, but as I understand, I cant accept comment as answer.

Comment: You don’t accept comments. You accept answers such as the one posted above. They may well be others and you select the one which best answers your question in your opinion. You don’t have to but it is helpful.